# How to use UIViewController of a separate XIB with outlet in AppDelegate.cs? Outlet is always NULL

Tags: xamarin.ios

Weird thing here. I think I have done it before but it no longer seems to work.
Environment is now: Lion, MT 4.1, MD 2.6 RC, Xcode 3's Interface Builder.

- I have a universal app (template from MonoDevelop).
- I changed it to have one `AppDelegateBase` class where both, the iPhone and the iPad's app delegate inherit from.
- There is one MasterController.xib file that contains a `UITabBarController`.
- In IB I set the **file's owner** of this XIB to `AppDelegateBase`.
- I added a `UITabBarController` outlet and connected it to the corresponding controller.
- In MasterController.xib.designer.cs I can see that the connection is there. This is what MasterController.xib.designer.cs looks like:

  // Base type probably should be MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController or subclass
      [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("AppDelegateBase")]
      public partial class AppDelegateBase {

  ```
      private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITabBarController __mt_oTabBarController;
      [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("oTabBarController")]
      private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITabBarController oTabBarController {
          get {
              this.__mt_oTabBarController = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UITabBarController)(this.GetNativeField("oTabBarController")));
              return this.__mt_oTabBarController;
          }
          set {
              this.__mt_oTabBarController = value;
              this.SetNativeField("oTabBarController", value);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

But in my AppDelegatebase.cs, `this.oTabBarController` is **always NULL**. What is wrong here?
The only difference to earlier projects is the fact that I have an additional XIB that contains a controller that I will use in the iPhone AND the iPad and therefore don't want to duplicate in the iPhones and the iPad's XIB.

Do I have to laod the MasterController.xib before I can do things to it? How? Puzzled.

Comment: How is MasterController.xib loaded?

Comment: Not at all, that's what I assume is the problem. I guess I'll have to use some LoadNib() - but how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the File's Owner to AppDelegateBase. Set it to the controller you want to use (in this case, a UITabBarController). In both MainWindowIPad.xib and MainWindowIPhone.xib, add a UITabBarController, connect it to an outlet in AppDelegate in each one and set its NIB Name field to MasterController.

<del>What you have done so far is correct. But you also need to load the XIB that contains the controller you want displayed.</del>

<del>Since it is MasterController.xib the first one that will be loaded, set it as the app's main interface file in the project settings in MonoDevelop, under iPhone Application. Both "Main interface file" and "iPad interface file".</del>

<del>Don't forget to add the controller's view to a window. You can instantiate that through code, or just add it to the XIB and connect it to an outlet in your AppDelegateBase object.</del>

<del>If you want to load the XIB through code, consider the following snippet:</del>

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("MasterController", this, null);
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the name is maybe misleading. "MasterController" does not mean it is the main XIB. There are MainWindowIPad.xib and MainWindowIPhone.xib. Those are also setup in Mono Develop for the main interface files. The MasterController.xib contains controllers that are supposed to be shared across both devices. I tried the LoadNib() but it fails when executed in AppDelegate.cs. Where do I have to call it? What is "this" in your example?

Comment: But this is not what I want. If I have to add a UITabBarController two both XIBs (iPhone and iPad), why would I have a third XIB with a  third UITabBarController? All I want is: grab the UITabBarController from a separate XIB and then (in code) add it as the iPhones RootViewController or as the iPads split view master controller. Therefore I want a UITabBarController outlet in my base AppDelegate. That outlet should connect to the controller from the separate XIB.

Comment: The fact that you will add view controllers in two different XIBs, does not mean that you will have two controllers at runtime. This is why you have to set their NIB Name to the name of the XIB that contains the actual controller. These will only act as a link to your tab bar controller.

Comment: I understand that. But if one day I decide to no longer have a UITabBarController but let's say a UINavigationController, I will have to change 3 XIBs (2 placeholders, one real thing) instead of changing the real controller only. I can't believe I have to add a "dummy". If I don't use IB, I would have my UITabBarController in code and I could add a new MyUITabBarController() to the iPad and to the iPhone and the layouts could still be made in IB...do you see my point?